# Update only one row in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using `Sequelize` as ORM along with `express.js` Below is my minimalistic table structure.

```
Id  status          phone

1     0             09620701828
2     0             09620701828
```

Now when an api request is to make on an end-point then I have to update status for last id belonging to a particular phone that I am getting from request. Raw MySql query for which will be `UPDATE table SET status=1 where phone='09620701828' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

How I can achieve the same using Sequelize update method. Below is what I have tried

```
models.customerLeadFeedback.update(
    {status: 1},
    { 
        where: {phone : '09620701828'},
        order: [['id', 'DESC']],
        limit : 1

    }).then(function () {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })`
```

But order by clause is not working for above and updating status for id 1. Can anyone help me with this without using raw query in `sequelize`.

Answer (score 14):

It would appear that Sequelize's`Model#update` function doesn't support ordering - see the docs at http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows

If you really want to target the row by ordering, you could fetch the row first, then update it:

```
models.customerLeadFeedback.findOne(
  {status: 1},
  { 
    where: {phone : '09620701828'},
    order: [['id', 'DESC']]
}).then(function (record) {
  return record.update({status: 1});
}).then(function (record) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

It's less efficient, using two queries instead of one, but currently looks like your only option if you don't want to use raw queries.

Comment: I think in first query you forgot to change update to findOne or findAll rest it would work and I think using raw query will be more efficient then.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed that. You might want to raise an issue/PR on the sequelize github - from my loose knowledge of their code it should be a trivial addition

Comment: return record.update({status: 1}) thank you this line save me.